# Equivalent of python walrus operator (:=) in c++11?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, arduino, python-3.8

Recently I have been using the `:=` operator in python quite a bit, in this way:

```py
if my_object := SomeClass.function_that_returns_object():
    # do something with this object if it exists
    print(my_object.some_attribute)
```

## The question

Is there any way to do this in c++11 without the use of `stdlib`?
for example in an arduino sketch if I wanted to use a method that may potentially return zero, such as:

```cpp
if(char * data = myFile.readBytes(data, dataLen))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the example?  You know it compiles?

Comment: I did not know that it compiled actually, I apologize for not testing this prior, this is just a thought that I had going to bed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's `:=` assignment expression operator (aka, the "walrus" operator) returns the *value* of an assignment.

C++'s `=` assignment operator (both [copy assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) and [move assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment), as well as [other assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)) does essentially the same thing, but in a different way. The result of an assignment is a *reference* to the object that was assigned to, allowing that object to be evaluated in further expressions.

So, the equivalent of:

```py
if my_object := SomeClass.function_that_returns_object():
    # do something with this object if it exists
    print(my_object.some_attribute)
```

Would be just like you showed:

```cpp
SomeType *object;
if ((my_object = SomeClass.function_that_returns_object())) {
    // do something with this object if it exists
    print(my_object->some_attribute);
}
```

If `function_that_returns_object()` returns a null pointer, the `if` evaluates `object` as false, otherwise it evaluates as true. The same can be done with other types, eg:

```cpp
int value;
if ((value = SomeClass.function_that_returns_int()) == 12345) {
    // do something with this value if it matches
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly, no.

As is mentioned in other answers, the c++ `=` operator already does most of what you want.  If have an existing variable then assignment to that variable returns a reference to it, so you can put that into an `if` condition:

```cpp
Foo* a_pointer;
if (a_pointer = some_function()) {
    //...
}
```

Here, the body of the if conditional will execute if `some_function` return a non-null pointer and `a_pointer` will be a copy of the pointer returned by `some_function`.

Unlike the walrus operator though, this has the limitation that `a_pointer` had to first be defined outside of the `if` condition.

---

C++17 adds something a bit closer, in that you can initialize a variable inside of the `if` condition with a special `if`-initializer syntax:

```cpp
if (Foo* a_pointer = some_function(); a_pointer) {
    //...
}
```

Note that the initializer still doesn't directly contribute to the truthiness of the `if` condition.  It's only the expression after the `;` that determines if the body of the `if` statement will execute.  In this case, `a_pointer` is initialized to be the value returned by `some_function` in the initializer and then the condition part checks if `a_pointer` is truthy.

Comment: `if (Foo* a_pointer = some_function())` works perfectly fine, though

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thank you! I was wanting to know if there was a way to reduce the lines needed for declaring the pointer, and assigning it down to 1 line from two, essentially was the only feature of the walrus operator that I was interested in, thank you also @PatrickParker, I don't know what version of c++ you are referring to, but I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [readBytes](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytes/) returns the number of bytes placed in the buffer (not a pointer), so I think you just need to do something like:

```cpp
if(myFile.readBytes(data, dataLen))
{
    // do something with data
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```